# Passing false values showing up as blank in var_dump

Tags: php

I am calling a stored procedure that takes an boolean argument. True values are easily passed as a 1 in my code, but false values are showing up blank. However, my var_dump shows that my value is actually false.

```
$form[$i]['photo_op'] = isset($_POST['photo_op'][$array_i]) ? $_POST['photo_op'][$array_i] : false;
```

My $_POST var_dump looks something like:

```
["photo_op"]=> bool(false) ["gala"]=> bool(true) ["chairman"]=> bool(false)
```

When I print out my values, it seems to be passing in empty strings for my 'photo_op' and 'chairman' fields:

```
foreach($form as $f){
    print "Photo OP: " . $f['photo_op'] . " | Gala: " . $f['gala'] . " | Chair: " . $f['chair'];
}
```

My output looks like:
Photo OP: | Gala: 1 | Chair:

My goal is to pass the false values to a stored procedure:

```
$final = insertAttendeeInfo($ind_id, $f['photo_op']);
```

The stored procedure looks something like:

```
function insertAttendeeInfo($ind_id, $photo){
   $insert = dbStoredProc('sp_remove_attendee_information', $ind_id, $photo);
   return;
}
```

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: So? You put `false` into the value and `print`ed it. Obviously got empty strings. What's the issue?

Comment: You forgot to mention what your database system is and how your actual DB call looks like.

Comment: And what do you want to see? `0` insead of blank? If yes, set (int) before each variable when you output them: (int)$f['photo_op']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you print a variable using the `print` function (or when you concatenate a variable to a string), its value gets converted to a string. A boolean `false` is converted to an empty string. If you want to see the true value of a variable use `var_dump` or `var_export` instead of `print`.

Comment: That makes sense Sander. But if I was passing a false value to an stored procedure, is there an appropriate way of passing false values?

Comment: Your database layer should know to convert PHP booleans to the SQL equivalent. What database (MySQL?) and what access layer (mysqli? PDO? Doctrine?) are you using?